# Wifi Direct Groups Memorised

Tags: android, wifi-direct

How can I delete the groups memorised by Wifi Direct?

If it is possible, what is the function allowing to delete groups?

thanks.

Comment: Here is [Wi-Fi Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html).

Comment: YES!! see -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/26242221/1815624 did...

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to delete groups with introspection:

```
Method deletePersistentGroupMethod = WifiP2pManager.class.getMethod("deletePersistentGroup", WifiP2pManager.Channel.class, int.class, WifiP2pManager.ActionListener.class);

for (int netid = 0; netid < 32; netid++) {
    deletePersistentGroupMethod.invoke(this.manager, this.channel, netid, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wi-Fi Direct Persistent groups are not implemented yet as far as I know (in Android API level 17).
So you don't have to bother deleting memorised groups as they don't exists (yet).