# How to create a non-persistent WiFi direct group on android?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

When `WifiP2pManager.connect` is called for the first time, there is a confirmation dialog on the target device to accept the connection.

On subsequent connections this confirmation is not asked anymore, the group is persisted on the device.

I don't want this behaviour because I want the device that initiates the connection to always be the group owner. When the group is persisted, the group owner cannot be changed.

Is there a way to create a temporary group instead of a persistent group? Or can I 'forget' the persistent group when I'm done with it?

Answer (score 6):

`WifiP2pManager.removeGroup` does not do what I want. It still remembers the group when you reconnect to the same device.

But I found there is a hidden method `WifiP2pManager.deletePersistentGroup` which I now call with reflection. It's not nice but it will need to do for now.

```
private void removeAndDeleteGroup(WifiP2pGroup wifiP2pGroup) {
    wifiP2PManager.removeGroup(wifiChannel, new SimpleLoggingActionListener("removeGroup"));
    try {
        Method getNetworkId = WifiP2pGroup.class.getMethod("getNetworkId");
        Integer networkId = (Integer) getNetworkId.invoke(wifiP2pGroup);
        Method deletePersistentGroup = WifiP2pManager.class.getMethod("deletePersistentGroup",
                WifiP2pManager.Channel.class, Integer.class, WifiP2pManager.ActionListener.class);
        deletePersistentGroup.invoke(wifiP2PManager, wifiChannel, networkId, new SimpleLoggingActionListener("deletePersistentGroup"));
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        Log.e("WIFI", "Could not delete persistent group", e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        Log.e("WIFI", "Could not delete persistent group", e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e("WIFI", "Could not delete persistent group", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: tried this which is the right idea but did not work?? though http://stackoverflow.com/a/26242221/1815624 did...

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't removeGroup in Wifip2pManager do what you need? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#removeGroup(android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel, android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener)

I would think calling that when you are done with your connection would cause it to ask to reconnect everytime.

Comment: No removeGroup does not remove the group **irony**