# Proper Way to Disconnect on Wifi Direct (Android) - removeGroup, channel close, or both?

Tags: android, wifi-direct

In API 27, Android added a close() method for WifiP2pManager.Channel.  Is this a better alternative to removeGroup?  Should I do both?  If I call close(), after closing, should I call initialize() to get a new channel, or should I just keep using the existing channel?  The documentation is unclear.

There is an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819076/disconnect-from-a-wifi-direct-group), but I believe that was before close() was added.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use and it works just fine.

```
public void disconnect() {
        if (mManager != null && mChannel != null) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            mManager.requestGroupInfo(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.GroupInfoListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGroupInfoAvailable(WifiP2pGroup group) {
                    if (group != null && mManager != null && mChannel != null) {
                        mManager.removeGroup(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                Log.d(TAG, "removeGroup onSuccess -");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(int reason) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "removeGroup onFailure -" + reason);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```